Stochastic independence between two "symmetric" events
Let $a_{1},a_{2},b_{1},b_{2}$ be four continuous i.i.d. random variables with support $[1,\bar{m}]$ and $1 \neq \bar{m}$. If needed, it can be assumed that they are all uniformly distributed on an interval $[1,\bar{m}]$, but I believe that it is not necessary to make use of their specific distribution. Let $A$ be the event $a_{1}a_{2} < b_{1}b_{2}$ and $B$ be the event $a_{1} + b_{1} \leq k_{1} \land a_{2} + b_{2} \leq k_{2}$, where $k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$ are arbitrary values from $(1,2\bar{m}]$ ($k_{1}$ and $k_{2}$ should not be equal to the left boundary of the support of $a_{1} + b_{1}$ and $a_{2} + b_{2}$). The goal is to show that $A$ and $B$ are stochastically independent.
There is an intuition why this would be the case. The event $A$ by itself has probability $1/2$ irrespective of the specific distributions of the random variables. Now, let the original random variables be supported on $[1,2]$ and let $k_{1} = 2.5$ and $k_{2} = 3.5$. Then, if $B$ is fulfilled, the sum $a_{1} + b_{1}$ cannot exceed $2.5$ and the sum $a_{2} + b_{2}$ cannot exceed $3.5$. Yet, under those restrictions we still have "equally many" combinations of the original random variables such that $A$ is true and such that $A$ is not true. For instance, if the realisations are $a_{1} = 1.1, b_{1} = 1.2$ and $a_{2} = 2, b_{2} = 1.3$, the event $A$ is not fulfilled, but I can now swap around the values and get the realisations $a'_{1} = 1.2, b'_{1} = 1.1$ and $a'_{2} = 1.3, b'_{2} = 2$ for which $A$ is fulfilled. Therefore, for any values $k_{1}$ and $k_{1}$ of the event $B$, there is a one-to-one correspdonence between the space of the variables where $A$ is fulfilled and the space where $A$ is not fulfilled so that these sets are intuitively "equally large" and, given the overall symmetry of the arrangement, should carry the same probability. Accordingly, the probability of $A$ given $B$ should still be $1/2$, showing that the two events are independent.
Does anyone have an idea how one could formalise this intuition to turn it into a general argument or how to prove independence of the events in some other way? While independence of $A$ and $B$ seems intuitively true, I spent a whole week on trying to formalise and generalise the argument in a way that goes beyond just saying: "This is obviously true because of symmetry." Thanks in advance -- I am happy to mention any helper in the paper where this problem has relevance.

By swapping $a_1$ with $b_1$ and $a_2$ with $b_2$, we see that
$$\mathbb P[A] = \mathbb P[\neg A]$$
And also that
$$\mathbb P[A\cap B] = \mathbb P[\neg A\cap B].$$
Therefore
$$\mathbb P[A\cap B] = \frac12\mathbb P[B]=\mathbb P[A]\mathbb P[B].$$

Hi Wei, that is great. Thanks a lot. Let me think about it before I green-tick your answer.

Hi Wei, thanks again. The crux of the argument is $P(A \cap B) = P(\neg A \cap B)$. If that is true, the independence of the event follows in the way you suggest. The problem is that if $B$ is true, then the variables $x := a_{1}a_{2}$ and $y := b_{1}b_{2}$ are not i.i.d. anymore (e.g., if $a_{1} = k_{1}$ then $b_{1}$ must be $1$). If $x$ and $y$ are i.i.d., then the probability of $x$ being greater than $y$ is $1/2$, but otherwise we only have an intuition. Therefore, I do not see the forcing argument why $P(A \cap B) = P(\neg A \cap B) = 1/2$. Any way to strengthen the "we see that..."?

It's true by the precise "swapping of variables" argument that I give in my answer. Nowhere did I make any argument based on conditional independence of $a_1a_2$ and $b_1b_2$.

$\text{Indeed.}\~~~A={ a_1a_2<b_1b_2}\text{ and }B={a_1+b_1<k_1\wedge a_2+b_2<k_2}\\neg A={ b_1b_2<a_1a_2}\text{ and }B={b_1+a_1<k_1\wedge b_2+a_2<k_2}\\quad\text{So, since $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$ are i.i.d., then:}\\Bbb P(A)=\Bbb P(\neg A)\text{ and }\Bbb P(B\cap A)=\Bbb P(B\cap\neg A).$
